# How to add helm charts as dependencies to my chart, but provide them with custom values.yml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am currently creating a helm chart for my fullstack application, and I would like to install a nats helm chart to it as a dependency. I know I can add it as a dependency in the Charts.yml file, but how can I provide the nats chart with a Values.yml to overrride the default nats chart values? What I would like is that when I do a helm install for my application, it also installs the nats dependency but with custom values.yml.

chart.yml dependency section

```
dependencies:
- name: nats
  repository: "https://nats-io.github.io/k8s/helm/charts"
  version: "0.11.0"
```

Then I run `helm dependency upgrade`. This creates a .tgz under my subcharts as follows

[image]

I would like to override the default values.yml which are present in the nats chart. I tried by adding the following to the parent values.yml but it did not work (as taken from https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/introduction/running/nats-kubernetes/helm-charts#clustering)

```
nats:
  cluster:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 5

    tls:
      secret:
        name: nats-server-tls
      ca: "ca.crt"
      cert: "tls.crt"
      key: "tls.key"
```

Do I need to unpack the chart for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in [Helm website](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart)

*Overriding Values from a Parent Chart*

so in your top level chart's `values.yaml`, use construct like this:

```
mysubchart:  # this is dependent sub-chart
  subchart-value-key: .... # this is key in subchart's values.yaml
```

**UPDATE**

In your case

```yaml
nats:
  cluster:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 5
```

works if I do `helm template .`, rendered statefullset seems to reflect values correctly:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-nats
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: nats-0.11.0
    
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nats
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.6.5"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      
      app.kubernetes.io/name: nats
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
  replicas: 5  # This value has been taken from values.yaml
```

So what exactly is not working?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I did try that previously, but it had not worked. So when we add a dependency, and run `helm dependency upgrade` it adds the tar.gz file to the chart folder. After that, adding the overriding values in the values.yml didn't work. Does this approach require that I extract the char and use it?

Comment: I updated the question to add more details!

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, it does work. The error was that because of a pvc issue, the stateful set deployed only 1 pod out of the three I was expecting.